# How to find specific in a cell that is next to the search string in excel file by c#?

Tags: c#, excel, text, find

I'd like to ask if anyone would know how to solve my problem. Trying to find a string in an excel file but I need to extract the value next in the cell and the value write in to the text file.
My individual steps:

1. Open Excel file
2. Find the cells
3. Create new text file
4. Write my value from xlxs file

It looks easy but I'm too stupid to create it :D

Form1:

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Windows.Forms;


namespace WindowsFormsApp2
{
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        OpenFile();
    }

    public void OpenFile()
    {
        Class1 excel = new Class1(@"C:\Users\info\Documents\Zkouska.xlsx",1) ;
        string path = @"C:\Users\info\Documents\new.txt";
        TextWriter tw = new StreamWriter(path, true);

       tw.Write(excel.ReadCell(0, 0));
    }
}
}
```

Class1:

```
using Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;
using System;
using _Excel = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;

   namespace WindowsFormsApp2
{
class Class1
{
    string path = "";
    _Application excel = new _Excel.Application();
    Workbook wb;
    Worksheet ws;

    public Class1(string path, int Sheet)
    {
        this.path = path;
        wb = excel.Workbooks.Open(path);
        ws = (Worksheet)wb.Worksheets[Sheet];
    }
    public string ReadCell(int i, int j)
    {
        i++;
        j++;
        string cellvalue = ws.Cells[i, j].Value2 as String; 
        if (cellvalue == "Z_KomSilnice_L (24200)/7 ")
        {
            return ws.Cells[i, j++];
        }
        else
            return "";
        }
} 
}
```

If I try to run it will show the error:

Microsoft.CSharp.RuntimeBinder.RuntimeBinderException: 'Operator '==' cannot be applied to operands of type 'System.__ComObject' and 'string''
in line:

```
string cellvalue = ws.Cells[i, j].Value2 as String;
```

Can I use to Contains(string)?

Perhaps I've described it enough, I'm new here so please be patient :)

Thank you so much for your advice :)

Comment: You are not doing any searching. You are just returning cells[1,2] or blank. You need some sort of loop to look in more than one cell.

Comment: @PalleDue I have to read cell by cell

Comment: Same problem, `Cells[...]` returns `System.__ComObject` and I don't know how to extract the data from it.

Comment: @rabejens will you get back when you find out?